# string array values are not printing

Tags: arrays, c, string, printf, byte

Do I need to include some spec library to work with 2D arrays?

Why different values are printed for similar definitions?

- `printf("%s", bbit[0])` for `bbit` array prints `0001001000110100mmmm0110011110001001101010111100110111101111�Bt�`,
- `printf("%s", arr[0])` for `arr` prints `0000`.

what could be the reason?
How to print the strings from array?
How to print byte representation of `array[i]` variable or any other variable?

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <stdint.h> //int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t  
#include <string.h>  /* strcat */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* strtol */

void main() {
    char bbit[16][4] = {
         "0000", "mmmm", "0010", "0011", // 0,1,2,3
         "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", // 4,5,6,7
         "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", // 8,8,10,11
         "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"  // 12,13,14,15
    }; 

    char* b4 = bbit[0];
    printf( "'%s'  %p  %d,  '%s' \n", b4, b4, *b4, bbit[0] ); 

    char* b5 = bbit[1];
    printf( "'%s'  %p  %d,  '%s' \n", b5, b5, *b5, bbit[1] ); 

    //prints '00000001001000110100mmmm0110011110001001101010111100110111101111�Bt�'  0x7ffc74421160  48,  '00000001001000110100mmmm0110011110001001101010111100110111101111�Bt�' 
    //prints '0001001000110100mmmm0110011110001001101010111100110111101111�Bt�'  0x7ffc74421164  48,  '0001001000110100mmmm0110011110001001101010111100110111101111�Bt�' 

    char arr[2][4] = { "0000",  "mmmm", };
    printf("'%s' has length %ld\n", arr[0], strlen(arr[0]));
    printf("'%s' has length %ld\n", arr[1], strlen(arr[1]));

    //prints '0100mmmm' has length 8
    //prints 'mmmm' has length 4
}
```

Comment: There are no strings in your arrays because the data is not null-terminated.

Comment: Strings in C are null-terminated. So arrays of length `4` are not enough to store your `"xxxx"`s

Comment: thank you for reminding. Do you know how to print byte representation of integer or string?

Answer (score 0):

The 2D length has to be increased by one = 5.
Because each string is terminated with a null character \0.

```
char bbit_rep[16][5] = {...}
//prints '0000'  0x7ffea750e4f0  48,  '0000'  

char arr[2][5] = { "0000",  "mmmm", };
printf("'%s' has length %ld\n", arr[0], strlen(arr[0]));
//prints '0000' has length 4
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments – the size is not sufficient to hold a null-terminator in each string. You need to increase the length by one to make it comfortable.

```
char bbit[16][5] = {
     "0000", "mmmm", "0010", "0011",
     "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
     "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
     "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
};
.
.
.
char arr[2][5] = { "0000",  "mmmm", };
```

After that, each string will correctly carry 4 characters and a null-terminator:

```
char str[5] = "ABCD"; // {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '\0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize arrays of 4 characters with 4 character strings: there is no space for any null terminator. Whenever you print one of them, `printf` keeps reading from memory until it finds a null byte. It there is none before the end of the array, the behavior is undefined and in your case `�Bt�` gets printed.

You should either limit the number of characters printed with a precision field:

```
char *b4 = bbit[0];
printf("'%.4s'\n", b4);  // prints '0000'
char *b5 = bbit[1];
printf("'%.4s'\n", b5);  // prints 'mmmm'
```

Or you can make the arrays larger:

```
char arr[2][5] = { "0000",  "mmmm", };
printf("'%s' has length %zu\n", arr[0], strlen(arr[0]));
printf("'%s' has length %zu\n", arr[1], strlen(arr[1]));

//prints '0100' has length 4
//prints 'mmmm' has length 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous comments are right, your arrays are not sufficient for storing length 4 strings, because you're not taking into account the null-termination character.
I suggest that you change your bi-dimensional arrays declaration in this way:

```
char bbit[16][5] = {
     "0000", "mmmm", "0010", "0011", // 0,1,2,3
     "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", // 4,5,6,7
     "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", // 8,8,10,11
     "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"  // 12,13,14,15
}
...
char arr[2][5] = { "0000",  "mmmm" };
```